# Is collection query (single), faster than a groupCollection query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection group query for Posts subcollections (can be nested up to into 2 subcollections)
ex.

```
firestore {
  users: <Collection> {
    posts: <subcollection> {... posts}
    types : <subcollection> {
     type1: <subcollection> : {
       posts: <subcollection> {... posts}
     } 
   }
}
```

For that i currently have a compound index and it is working well .

My question is, will be more performant to have 1 top level Collection Posts (denormalized with a cloud function) and query it instead?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection group queries use fundamentally the same indexing strategy as normal queries, so they should operate with the same performance.  Specifically, this means that the queries will [scale with the size of the result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603205/queries-scale-with-the-size-of-your-result-set-not-the-size-of-your-data-set), not with the size of the collection(s).

Comment: So in theory is the same you say

Comment: You're free to run your own benchmarks to see if there is a practical difference.

Comment: @YejielWahnich Did you end up running benchmarks yourself? I am facing the exact same problem as you (I also have a users collection and each user has a post sub-collection)