# can collectionGroup queries select all inner documents of a parent document

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

using latest flutter version with firestore , the below is an example of my DB design ,
[image]
and this ,
[image]

can collectionGroup ,
 ***Get all 'hours' where 'days' document ID is equal to '2019-11-09'***

coming from relational DB family this is vey simple , but am banging my head with firestore-flutter , please help me to achieve this , or should I re-design which would be lame .

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to be that specific in a collection group query.  A collection group query will always consider **all** collections with the same name.  It can't be focused on a subcollection nested specifically under another collection.  What you can do is query all of the document of all `hours` collection, and that will work no matter where it is nested.  If you need to narrow that down to a specific day, the you will need to add a new field for day, and filter all the hour documents on that day.

```
db.collectionGroup('hours').where('day', isEqualTo: 'whatever')
```

Comment: woudnt that mean to query the whole database instead of querying just a parent document , isnt that a massive performance hit ? Apart from collectionGroup is there any other solution firestore provides ?

Comment: Queries on Firestore are guaranteed to have performance that only depends on the number/size of the results you get, and not dependent on the amount of data they search. In words of a team mate: when you search our haystack the performance depends on the number of needles only, and not on the size of the haystack.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you guide me to any documentation or the tech behind explaining this performance claim , cant digest , even the hay and needle story .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603205/queries-scale-with-the-size-of-your-result-set-not-the-size-of-your-data-set