# Firebase Data Structure setup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As a complete novice when it comes to firebase I am struggling with the whole data structure concept as stupid as that may sound.
I am so use to relational databases that I think I am missing or just not getting the basic flow of NOSQL.
So my question is in relation to Documents and Subcollections etc. and wondering how I would structure the following data as my head is just not getting it.

Putting it as simply as possible here is my structure
There are companies who, have employees (Drivers). These Drivers would drive vehicles belonging to the company.
These vehicles would have pumps fitted to them which in turn have a pipeline fitted to them (up to 60 Pipes)
These vehicles and pumps are to be checked daily. Up to 10 items.
There would also need to be a separate record kept for Vehicle maintenance done at km or date intervals.
The pipeline is checked monthly all pipes (up to 60 in total)
Now with a relational database to structure this would be easy using key_fields and Primary_keys. In terms of firebase how would one structure Documents and Collections and at what point  would sub collections come into this and what would fit into sub collections.
As I have said for some reason I am just not getting these concepts.

Have tried watching tutorials but still not getting the penny to drop as they are varying terminolgies and suggestions.

Comment: Data models in NoSQL don't depends on your data structure alone, but also (in fact: mostly) on the exact use-cases of your app. Rather than trying to enumerate all of those, I recommend watching this excellent introductory series of videos: [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ).

Comment: Thanks Frank for the reply. I have watched these tuorials and yes they are very good. Even then though i thought I had it worked out in my head and then talk started on maps etc. I guess as i said I understand from a relational database pov however for some reason in my scenario i just cant fathom where sub collections etc come into it. I am assuming the company would be a top or root then drivers and employees vehicles would be a collection.pipes etc would be a sub collection and then perhaps the testing would be sub collections to pipes just my thinking it through

Comment: You're trying to model your data here, without specifying a use-case - which is a mistake when using NoSQL databases. Start with a single use-case (say: "show a list of companies") and then define a simple model for that (a single collection "companies"). Now go to the next use-case (say: "show the drivers for a single company") and model that. Here it gets interesting, because you need to decide if you store all drivers in a single top-level collection, or store them in a subcollection under each company doc. Hmm... let me put this in an answer...

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comments: in NoSQL you typically model your data for the use-cases of your app, not for some perceived database normal form.

---

So let's start with a single use-case, say: "show a list of companies". A simple model for that would be to have a top-level collection "companies".

---

Now go to the next use-case, say: "show the drivers for a single company". Here it gets interesting, because you need to decide if you store all drivers in a single top-level collection, or store them in a subcollection under each company doc.

In Firestore there is going to be no difference in read-performance between these two approaches, as reading from a collection does **not** depend on the number of documents in that collection. This is one of the biggest differences from SQL databases. For more on this, see [Queries scale with the size of your result set, not the size of your data set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46603205)

So instead, decide based on the use-cases of your app.

- If you only (or almost only) ever want to show the drivers for a single company, it makes more sense to store the drivers for that company in a subcollection under the company doc.
- If you regularly want to show the drivers across multiple companies, it makes more sense to store them as a single top-level collection.

In both cases I recommend storing the company ID in a field in each driver document. Even though it's not immediately needed in the first scenario, it often comes in handy as use-case evolve.

---

In this way you'll add more and more use-cases, and evolving your data model.

If you get stuck on modeling for one specific use-case, more folks here are likely able to help.

Comment: Hi Frank, Sorry for not responding and thanking you ealier took a few days vacation and no technology. Thanks for the help. I think i am getting it in my head now. Just 1 more question if I may, with the use of ids do they "relate" back somehow through similar to the key fields in a relational database? to marry the data together?

Comment: The only actual relational type Firestore has is its `DocumentReference`, but (even though you can write that to and read it from a field) it does fairly little. Outside of that, references are just values as far as Firestore is concerned - which is one of the reasons it can scale its performance so well.